# Defining the appropriate time window to absorbe the variability of qualitative effects in a time series

Tags: time-series

An aerial survey is conducted several times a year to count the number of animals in a given zone. So for each survey, I have a dependent variable: **Nobs** (Number of observed animals) associated with independent variables: **observer**, **pilot**, **month**, **year**. I want to choose the most appropriate time window (1, 2, 4 years) to estimate the evolution of **Nobs** over time with the variability due to the variables: **observer**, **pilot**, **month** absorbed, meaning that I have sufficient diversity in each time window to remove their impact.

I have tried applying a multi-way ANOVA which provides the significance of the difference due to the various independent variables. However, one assumption for the ANOVA which is the normality of the residuals is not met (Shapiro-Wilk test) and it does not provide the appropriate time window to analyze the data. For the same reasons, ANCOVA is not suited.

What approach should I use to justify the most appropriate time window to evaluate the evolution of Nobs in time?